# React Mui DataGrid use Components Pagination rowsPerPageOptions is not shown

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I use Mui DataGrid components Pagination,but my onPageSizeChange and rowsPerPageOptions is not show .

```
<DataGrid
    rows={posts}
    columns={columns}
    pageSize={pageSize}
    onPageSizeChange={(newPageSize) =>
        setPageSize(newPageSize)
    }
    rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 20, 50]}
    autoHeight={true}
    onRowClick={(rowData) => {
        window.location.href = `./${config.hashRouter}/EditPost?PostID=${rowData.id}`;
    }}
/>
```

[image: Screenshot of result]

```
<DataGrid
    rows={posts}
    columns={columns}
    pageSize={pageSize}
    onPageSizeChange={(newPageSize) =>
        setPageSize(newPageSize)
    }
    rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 20, 50]}
    autoHeight={true}
    onRowClick={(rowData) => {
        window.location.href = `./${config.hashRouter}/EditPost?PostID=${rowData.id}`;
    }}
    components={{
        Pagination: CustomPagination,
    }}
/>
```

[image: Screenshot of result]

Answer (score 1):

I innser select in my Custompagination

```
<FormControl variant="standard">
                    <Select
                        labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
                        id="demo-simple-select"
                        value={pageSize}
                        label="Size"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    >
                        <MenuItem value={10}>10</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value={20}>20</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value={30}>30</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value={40}>40</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value={50}>50</MenuItem>
                    </Select>
                </FormControl>
```